# Play another video when one ends

Tags: video, jwplayer

I want to play my default or any other file when one video ends. is there any method to detect end of video in JWPLAYER.

Any example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use playlist like this :

```
var myVideo = "yourDefaultVideoURL";

jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "/assets/sintel.jpg",
        sources: [
            { file: "/assets/sintel.mp4", label: "360p" },
            { file: myVideo , label: "720p HD" }
        ],
        title: "Sintel Movie Trailer"
    }]
});
```

documentation here : http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28842/working-with-playlists/

Answer (score 0):

You can use onComplete() and load() using our JavaScript API, to do this:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<center><div id='my-video'></div></center>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-kNspJqnJ.mp4"
});
jwplayer().onComplete(function() { jwplayer().load({file:"http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4"});jwplayer().play() });
</script>
```